# Estimated work not rolling up on PBI's in Scrum - TFS2013

Tags: tfs, scrum

I have modified the WIT To add the estimated work on scrum task template but it's the values on not roll-up on the PBI.

Could you please provide some insight to calculate the values? Does it possible on SCRUM?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I had look on the documentation but it says the Original estimation is availanle for Agile and CMMI.

◦Original Estimate (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate): The amount of work required to complete a task. (Agile and CMMI)

My project is created with SCRUM and I've edited task WIT To have the original estimate but it's not doing the work while appearing on the PBI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your team project was created using the Visual Studio Scrum process template, only Remaining Work is defined in the task by default. Even though you have customized the WIT by yourself, however this will not roll up on PBI by TFS. As you have seen the [Rollup requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields#rollup-requirements).

It's also reflect in report area and cube:

> The cube contains all the fields of all your collections on the TFS server. A project created with the Agile or CMMI process template will
>   have that field and it will create the field in the cube. **Scrum
>   projects don't have that field, so if your project is created with the
>   Scrum process template your Task work item does not have that field**
>   and the value in the cube will be blank.

Actually, Scrum isn't interested in the original estimate, tracking "spent time" is not really in line the philosophy of Scrum. Suggest you stay away from tasks-in-hours marrying up to people-in-hours with using Scrum template.

Highly recommend you first go through the discussion in below threads especially  *Jesse's* post, then consider if use estimated work in scrum:

- [Original Estimation in TFS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75bc0b90-70df-4e48-a8c4-f527a7aeeeea/original-estimation-in-tfs?forum=tfsprocess)
- [How to Find Actual Time Spent on a TASK in TFS 2013 by using the scrum template](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8458361e-1d99-46b8-9e7f-b67b61073b2d/how-to-find-actual-time-spent-on-a-task-in-tfs-2013-by-using-the-scrum-template?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)